# Android Studio Emulator: API 26 ARM WebView Crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-8.0-oreo

I downloaded an arm64 Android Oreo SDK 26 image in macOS running in Apple Silicon. Upon running the virtual device the WebView is crashing and this affects my project as well which is crashing on startup as it has dependency on it. Is this a known bug with this image and if yes, is there a workaround?

```
Chromium WebView package does not exist
android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: Failed to load WebView provider: No WebView installed
    at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewContextAndSetProvider(WebViewFactory.java:334)
    at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:398)
    at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
```

I also noticed that arm images has no Play API and even Google API unlike its x86 counterpart for lower SDK version.

Comment: The WebView implementation is located in a separate APK file. If none is installed and/or configured this would explain the error message. Usually there is a WebView APK or just Google Chrome installed which can be configured in developer settings to provide the WebView implementation. So first check there what possibilities you have and if there is none download one of the APKs and install it manually.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, too.  My system is Mac OS X M2. 

This issue only happens in the API 26 arm image. 

In my testing, API 24, 25,  ...., 27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34 is working for the WebView.  Only API 26 will be crashed when I use the webview.